# Aviary integration with Android Studio: Could not find com.aviary.android.feather.sdk:aviary-sdk:3.4.3.350

Tags: android, aviary

I'm trying to add aviary via maven through Android Studio but I keep getting this error:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':myproj'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':myproj:_devDebugCompile'.
>   Could not find com.aviary.android.feather.sdk:aviary-sdk:3.4.3.350.
>        Required by:
>            myproj:myproj:unspecified > myproj.libraries:mylib:unspecified

Comment: I got an identical error. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: An e-mail I got from an Aviary representative. I'm going to follow-up when them soon.

"Hi!

Thanks for reaching out to Aviary! Sorry that you are having integration issues! I'd be happy to help.

The beta sdk is not currently supported. We are expecting to resolve any issues next week.

I am going to discuss the issue with our team. I'll let you know once I have updates."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had a bunch of conflicting libraries. Had to exclude a few. My configuration looks like this:

```
compile ('com.aviary.android.feather.sdk:aviary-sdk:3.4.3.350') {
        exclude module: 'hlistview'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'commons-io'
    }
```

To see what libraries you need to exclude run `./gradlew -q dependencies` in your app module directory and exclude all libraries that conflict with yours.

Comment: If you're using Picasso (square), you might need to exclude it as well.

Comment: The libraries you exclude will be completely dependent on library dependencies included in your project. The best way of knowing which libraries to exclude is running ./gradlew -q dependencies.